# Getting [Object Object] in angular2 application

Tags: html, angular, rest, ngrx-effects

[image]I have developed angular2 application using ngrx/effects for making http calls. I have used [GIT](https://github.com/tui2tone/ngrx-effect-example) as reference application. Once the response come from http, i am not able to display it on screen. Its showing [object Object]. Here is my code.

HTML page linked to component.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left-container cf">
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Configuration">{{jsons}}</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Captured Output">
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
</div>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
        export class ExperimentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

      jsons: Observable<any>;
      isLoading: Observable<any>;

      constructor(
        private store: Store<fromStore.State>
      ) {
        this.isLoading = store.select(fromStore.getIsLoading);
        this.jsons = store.select(fromStore.getJson);
        console.log(this.jsons)
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.store.dispatch(new jsonAction.GetJson());
        // this.jsons = this.store.select(fromStore.getJson);
      }
    }
```

Effects.ts

```
        export class GetJsonEffects {

      @Effect() json$ = this.actions$.ofType(Act.GET_JSON)
        .map(toPayload)
        .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
        .mergeMap(([ payload, store ]) => {

          return this.http$
            .get(`http://localhost:4000/data/`)
            .map(data => {
              return new Act.GetJsonSuccess({ data: data })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              return Observable.of(
                new Act.GetJsonFailed({ error: error })
              );
            })
        });


      constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private http$: HttpClient,
        private store$: Store<fromStore.State>
      ) {}
    }
```

Comment: What part of your code is related to `[Object Object]`. Where does it show it? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: If you want to display json objects you can use the `json` pipe: `{{jsons|json}}`

Comment: Thanks for reply. if i use {{jsons | json}} i am getting error - ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see, the result of `store.select()` is an observable. You cannot data bind to it directly.

You can either:

Use the `async` pipe to make the UI subscribe to the observable for you and extract the data, like:

```
<mat-tab label="Configuration">{{jsons | async}}</mat-tab>
```

Or subscribe yourself to the observable.

```
export class ExperimentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

     jsonSubscription = store.select(fromStore.getJson)
          .subscribe(jsons => this.jsons = jsons);

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.jsonSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
      jsons: any;

     // ...
}
```

That's one thing:

**If you are using `Http` service (from `@angular/http` module):**

The other thing is that you are returning the Response object not the JSON extracted from it. The `map()` in your effect needs to call `data.json()`. Like:

```
      return this.http$
        .get(`http://localhost:4000/data/`)
        .map(data => {
          return new Act.GetJsonSuccess({ data: data.json() })
        })
```

Or, as I like, add another `map()` to make things clear:

```
      return this.http$
        .get(`http://localhost:4000/data/`)
        // You could also create an interface and do:
        //   `response.json() as MyInterfaceName` 
        //   to get intellisense, error checking, etc
        .map(response => response.json())
        .map(data => {
          return new Act.GetJsonSuccess({ data: data })
        })
```

**If you are using `HttpClient` service (from `@angular/common/http` module):**
(Available in Angular v4.3+)

In this case you don't need to call `.json()` yourself, it does it for you, so you don't need that first `.map()` I suggested.

You can also tell TypeScript about the type you expect the JSON to match by calling the `get()` like this:

```
      return this.http$
        .get<MyInterfaceName>(`http://localhost:4000/data/`)
        .map(data => {
          return new Act.GetJsonSuccess({ data: data.json() })
        })
```

The `get<MyInterfaceName>()` bit will make Angular tell TypeScript that the JSON object matches the `MyInterfaceName`, so you'll get intellisense and error checking based on this (at compile time only, none of this affects runtime in anyway).

[`HttpClient` Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: Hi Meligy, Thanks for reply. I tried the changes what you have mentioned. I am getting some errors in Effects.ts Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: `this.http$.get(`http://localhost:4000/data/`)` should return `Observable<Response>`, so `.map(response  => ...)` should have `response` as a `Response` not `Object`. When you hover on it, is that what you see? Is your real code different than posted here?

Comment: Also maybe you have too many brackets or something that your `mergeMap()` which should contain all this code is closed and the `map()` is run after that or something. Ensure it's called directly after the `.get(`http://localhost:4000/data/`)` and the `get()` call has only one closing bracket

Comment: Hi Meligy, posted code and the one i am using both are same. Yes, the http.get() returns an object. In that object .json() method is not there. And using Redux Devtool i checked the state**Json Success**, I am able to see json data. I have checked the brackets also. I am facing problem in displaying data from store.

Comment: It seemed you are using `HttpClient` not `Http` then (in Angular 4.3+, imported from `@angular/common/http`), which does the `.json()` for you. In this case you don't need it. And just the `async` pipe is needed. BTW, in `HttpClient`, you can call `get()` like this `.get<MyInterfaceName>(`http://localhost:4000/data/`)` so TypeScript uses this type instead of object. This does nothing in runtime but only tells TypeScript to use `MyInterfaceName` for intellisense / error checking, etc.

Comment: I updated the reply to reflect the `HttpClient` case